# How to close unnamed, unmodified buffer when hidden?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, hidden-buffers

I'm currently trying to set this up using the following autocommand, but it is not working for some reason.

```lua
-- Delete unnamed, unmodified buffers when they are hidden.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufHidden", {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("UserAutoClose", {}),
  callback = function(args)
    if vim.bo[args.buf].buftype == "nofile" then
      vim.api.nvim_buf_delete(args.buf, {})
    end
  end,
})
```

Furthermore, this autocommand produces the following error when closing a tab (with `:tabclose`) that has only one attached buffer.

```
Error detected while processing BufHidden Autocommands for "*":
E937: Attempt to delete a buffer that is in use: [No Name]
Error executing lua callback: /home/pwnalone/.config/chad/lua/custom/autocmds.lua:6: Failed to unload buffer.
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_delete'
        /home/pwnalone/.config/chad/lua/custom/autocmds.lua:6: in function </home/pwnalone/.config/chad/lua/custom/autocmds.lua:4>
```

**NOTE:** I know that buffers are not scoped to individual tabs by default in Neovim, but I'm using the [NvChad](https://nvchad.com/) distribution as my base configuration, which [provides the ability to group buffers by tab](https://nvchad.com/docs/api#gototab).